# Can Google Cloud CDN be used for businesses that are not deployed on Google Cloud?

Tags: google-cloud-cdn

My website is not deployed on Google Cloud, can I use [Google Cloud CDN](https://cloud.google.com/cdn/docs/overview)?

Answer (score 0):

Google CDN only works with Google load balancer and cloud storage origins. This means if you are not hosting your website on GCP (Google Cloud Platform) then you can’t use their CDN.

In other words, it doesn’t support external origins yet. Simple. See [before you begin](https://cloud.google.com/cdn/docs/using-cdn) section.